# find kernel config option in menuconfig

Tags: linux, kernel, gentoo

I've upgraded my gentoo-sources today to 3.3.8, and now I am looking at **diff** between old kernel's **defconfig** and old kernel's **.config**: there are about 20 changes. I want to apply this changes manually to new kernel's menuconfig.

Where can I find tool like:

```
menuconfig-find -v 3.3.8-gentoo AMD
>> [0] Device Drivers
       -> IOMMU Hardware Support (IOMMU_SUPPORT [=y])
         -> AMD IOMMU support (AMD_IOMMU [=y])
>> [1] Device Drivers
       -> Memory Technology Device (MTD) support (MTD [=n])
         -> Mapping drivers for chip access
...
<< :goto 1 ENTER
```

PS I dont like menuconfig's build-in search because it is obviously nousable:

1. no bashcompletion
2. should run 2 menuconfigs simultaneously in different sessions
3. result is just a plain text and I couldn't select entry and press "go to this menu entry now"

Comment: Gee, I thought that navigating through 'menuconfig' was a sign of skill.  If it's going to be easy to re-configure a kernel with search capability, then is everybody an expert kernel hacker?  :-)

Comment: gentoo way is to provide the most convenient utilities. I cant find such convinient utility for search in kernel config =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> gentoo way is to provide the most convenient utilities.

A very convenient utility is Git. Then you can keep track of the changes you've been doing to the config and take only those that you need in the end; but well, given that you don't have that you'll indeed have to go manually through them.

---

You kind of have two contradicting statements here:

- You manually want to apply the textual diff changes.
- You want to use the GUI for that.

That isn't going to work, while one could improve the kernel for those who are search addicted it just isn't there, most likely there isn't a menu diff either. So, you will want to make these changes manually in the text form, not in the GUI.

But then, what does each `CONFIG_` line mean?

Now, that's where the GUI search comes useful for.

---

But that means two sessions, right, we have another convenient utility for that: Try a split `screen`.

In the top one you could have your merge utility, and in the bottom one you can do GUI searching.

The rest depends on your copy / paste skills...